# Using lxml xpath to parse xml file

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I'm using lxml XPath to parse the following xml file

```
<urlset
    xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
    xmlns:news="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-news/0.9"
    xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">
    <url>
        <loc>
    https://www.reuters.com/article/us-campbellsoup-thirdpoint/campbell-soup-nears-deal-with-third-point-to-end-board-challenge-sources-idUSKCN1NU11I
    </loc>
        <image:image>
            <image:loc>
    https://www.reuters.com/resources/r/?m=02&d=20181126&t=2&i=1328589868&w=&fh=&fw=&ll=460&pl=300&r=LYNXNPEEAO0WM
    </image:loc>
        </image:image>
        <news:news>
            <news:publication>
                <news:name>Reuters</news:name>
                <news:language>eng</news:language>
            </news:publication>
            <news:publication_date>2018-11-26T02:55:00+00:00</news:publication_date>
            <news:title>
    Campbell Soup nears deal with Third Point to end board challenge: sources
    </news:title>
            <news:keywords>Headlines,Business, Industry</news:keywords>
            <news:stock_tickers>NYSE:CPB</news:stock_tickers>
        </news:news>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

Python code sample

```
import lxml.etree
import lxml.html
import requests

def main():
    r = requests.get("https://www.reuters.com/sitemap_news_index1.xml")

    namespace = "http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-news/0.9"
    root = lxml.etree.fromstring(r.content)


    records = root.xpath('//news:title', namespaces = {"news": "http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-news/0.9"})
    for record in records:
        print(record.text)


    records = root.xpath('//sitemap:loc', namespaces = {"sitemap": "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"})
    for record in records:
        print(record.text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Currently, I'm XPath to get all *URL* and *title*, but this is not what I want because I don't know which URL belongs to which title. My question is how to get each `<url>`, then loop each `<url>` as item to get corresponding `<loc>` and `<news:keywords>` etc. Thanks!

Edit:
Expecting output

```
foreach <url>
      get <loc>
      get <news:publication_date>
      get <news:title>
```

Comment: Can you post an example of your expected output?

Comment: @BernardL Expected output added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use relative XPath to get from each title to its associated URL:

```
ns = {
    "news": "http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-news/0.9",
    "sitemap": "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9",
    "image": "http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1"
}

r = requests.get("https://www.reuters.com/sitemap_news_index1.xml")
root = lxml.etree.fromstring(r.content)

for title in root.xpath('//news:title', namespaces=ns):
    print(title.text)

    loc = title.xpath('ancestor::sitemap:url/sitemap:loc', namespaces=ns)
    print(loc[0].text)
```

Exercise: Rewrite this to get from the URL to the associated title instead.

Note: The titles (and potentially the URLs as well) seem to be HTML-escaped. Use the `unescape()` function

```
from html import unescape
```

to unescape them.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

```
from datetime import datetime
from html import unescape
from lxml import etree
import requests

r = requests.get("https://www.reuters.com/sitemap_news_index1.xml")
root = etree.fromstring(r.content)

ns = {
    "news": "http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-news/0.9",
    "sitemap": "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9",
    "image": "http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1"
}

for url in root.iterfind("sitemap:url", namespaces=ns):
    loc = url.findtext("sitemap:loc", namespaces=ns)
    print(loc)
    title = unescape(url.findtext("news:news/news:title", namespaces=ns))
    print(title)
    date = unescape(url.findtext("news:news/news:publication_date", namespaces=ns))
    date = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+00:00')
    print(date)
```

The rules of thumb are:

**Try not use xpath**. Instead of using xpath, use find, findall, iterfind. xpath is a more complex algorithm than just find, findall or iterfind and it takes more time and resources.

Use *iterfind* instead of using findall. Because iterfind will yield return the items. That is to say it will return one item at a time. Thus it uses less memory.

Use *findtext* if all you need is text.

A more general rule is to read the [official document](https://lxml.de/4.4/api/lxml.etree._ElementTree-class.html).

Firstly, let's create 3 for-loop function and compare them.

```
def for1():
    for url in root.iterfind("sitemap:url", namespaces=ns):
        pass

def for2():
    for url in root.findall("sitemap:url", namespaces=ns):
        pass

def for3():
    for url in root.xpath("sitemap:url", namespaces=ns):
        pass
```

| function | time |
| --- | --- |
| `root.iterfind` | 70.5 µs ± 543 ns |
| `root.findall` | 72.3 µs ± 839 ns |
| `root.xpath` | 84.8 µs ± 567 ns |

We can see that iterfind is the fastest as expected.

Next, let's check the statements inside the for loop.

| statement | time |
| --- | --- |
| `url.xpath('string(news:news/news:title)', namespaces=ns)` | 15.7 µs ± 112 ns |
| `url_item.xpath('news:news/news:title', namespaces=ns)[0].text` | 14.4 µs ± 53.7 ns |
| `url_item.find('news:news/news:title', namespaces=ns).text` | 3.74 µs ± 60 ns |
| `url_item.findtext('news:news/news:title', namespaces=ns)` | 3.71 µs ± 40.3 ns |

From the above table, we can see that find/findtext is 4 times faster than xpath. And findtext is even faster than find.

This answer takes only 3.41 ms ± 53 µs, compared to Tomalak's 8.33 ms ± 52.4 µs